# Erlang records with both type and value restrictions as well as default values

Tags: types, erlang, default-value, records, restrictions

I am trying to write a record which represents a bank account:

```
-record(account, {  name :: atom(),
                    type :: atom(),
                    balance = 0 :: integer()  }).
```

I also want to restrict the balance to always be `>= 0`. How do I do this?

Comment: Note that while you can declare the type to be a non-negative integer this **does not** enforce anything at run-time, it is really only a comment. You can set the balance field to any value you choose and any type.

Comment: @rviding How can I enforce this behavior at runtime (without function guards)? Or does this pseudo-static typing just not exist in Erlang?

Comment: You can't! Erlang is too dynamic, so static typing does not exist in the language and the compiler does not use this information. It is only for documentation and for the type checking tool dialyzer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like `balance = 0 :: 0 | pos_integer()` might do the trick.

edit wasn't sure it existed, but `non_neg_integer()` would be better :

```
balance = 0 :: non_neg_integer()
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that existed either. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Beware that as said Robert Virding this is only information for the reader, documentation or tools. It doesn't prevent balance to be negative or anything else (like an atom). If it is important in your code you must use guard like is_integer(B) andalso B >= 0 before using it and/or modifying a balance.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal, I'll be sure to use those guards. :)

Answer (score 7):

As noted by others, the type specifications are merely inputs to analysis tools like [PropEr](https://github.com/manopapad/proper) and [Dialyzer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html). If you need to enforce the invariant `balance >= 0`, the account type should be encapsulated, accessible only to functions that respect the invariant:

```
-module(account).

-record(account, { name :: atom(),
                   type :: atom(),
                   balance = 0 :: non_neg_integer() }).

%% Declares a type whose structure should not be visible externally.
-opaque account() :: #account{}.
%% Exports the type, making it available to other modules as 'account:account()'.
-export_type([account/0]).

%% Account constructor. Used by other modules to create accounts.
-spec new(atom(), atom(), non_neg_integer()) -> account().
new(Name, Type, InitialBalance) ->
    A = #account{name=Name, type=Type},
    set_balance(A, InitialBalance).

%% Safe setter - checks the balance invariant
-spec set_balance(account(), non_neg_integer()) -> account().
set_balance(Account, Balance) when is_integer(Balance) andalso Balance >= 0 ->
    Account#account{balance=Balance};
set_balance(_, _) -> error(badarg). % Bad balance
```

Notice how this resembles a class with private fields in object-oriented languages like Java or C++. By restricting access to "trusted" constructors and accessors, the invariant is enforced.

This solution doesn't provide protection against *malicious* modification of the `balance` field. It's entirely possible for code in another module to ignore the "opaque" type specification and replace the balance field in the record (since [records are just tuples](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the example and the warning!